# Find My Friends Settings

Tags: iphone

We’re looking to make sure we know where our daughter is and so are using the **Find My Friends** app on iOS 11. We’ve set things up within restrictions however the app settings have changed. We’re guessing that this has been done through iCloud on her iMac.

Is there any way to stop the settings being changed again once we put them back?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the restriction settings by following the instructions in the Apple knowledge base article, [Find My Friends: Set restrictions](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19441). It will let you passcode protect the changes, along with other options.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.